# Spark-submit in cluster mode makes the application view unusable?

Tags: apache-spark

I use Jenkins to run a `spark-submit` every hour with `--deploy-mode cluster` set. Is approach recommended? Because some things don't seem to work.

When I go to my spark server, and press the Application name, it tries to go to my computer on that port (which is firewalled) instead of the server. With `--deploy-mode cluster` I'd expect to be able to see this on the spark master since the `spark-submit` returns immediately in this mode.

Also, I can't seem to open the DAG. Is that related?

The full command I use is `spark-submit --master spark://mysparkserver:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --class someClass --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true http://theJarUrl`

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Despite the fact that you can enable event logging on spark master, you also need to specify it in `spark-submit` using `--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=/opt/spark/spark-events`. After you can watch the events on the spark-master by clicking the application name. It will also enable inspecting finished applications.

Despite that the DAG visualisation still doesn't work for me. If anyone has a suggestion for that, please leave a comment.

Comment: what do you mean by "DAG visualisation still doesn't work for me" - what are you seeing?

Comment: A bunch of empty dots, instead of the DAG. When I spark in loca mode, it does work. https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/65597/456874/PU66TrvQjHNsPQt/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-22%20at%2020.23.33.png

Comment: I've seen this too - couldn't find the solution, but I have a workaround: it does work when I switch to a different browser :)

Comment: That's it! Thanks! It just doesn't work in Chrome. For others: it will be fixed via Spark 1.6.1. [Here's the official bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13088)